# I just got downvoted on 10 questions - why would that be?

Tags: support

I just got downvoted on 10 answers on this site with no comment added to any of them. I assume it's not a mere coincidence. Possible reasons as far as I can tell:

1. Something happened to a user who had upvoted me on all those questions.
2. Someone decided they don't like me and just downvoted a bunch of my answer.

It's probably not 1., since I haven't seen a "user removed" notice. If it's 2. - what do I do? And if it isn't - are there other possible causes?

Comment: It looks like it's been 24 hours, and it's not reversed yet. I'm going to wait a *little* bit longer (another 24 hours) just in case something changes and the script catches it on its next run, and then I'll get SE staff to look into it if it still hasn't been reversed.

Comment: Sometimes I provide what I think is a great answer, and get a downvote with no comment, or a useless comment like "off-topic" or "doesn't answer the question".  Sometimes I need to go back and fix an answer and sometimes people are jerks.

Comment: @MikeP: And has this ever happened to you in _10_ questions within about 30 minutes?

Comment: I see the votes have been corrected as of 3:00 UTC. Guess that script runs a little less frequently than 24 hours :) but looks like all is good now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Something happened to a user who had upvoted me on all those questions.

If a user were deleted, you would lose their up votes, but the votes would not be transformed into down votes.

> Someone decided they don't like me and just downvoted a bunch of my answer.

This is more likely: you might have been targeted by someone. Stack Exchange has a script that detects this kind of bad behaviour and reverts the down votes. You just have to wait a bit. For more information, read the following post on the main meta:

[What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: Ok, I'll wait and see what happens in 24h.

Comment: Same boat, would kill for a "must comment in order to downvote" requirement, with minimum word count.